# Embedding Lua in C++

Tags: c++, lua, undefined, embedding

I've been trying to embed lua in a c++ application but to no avail since the compiler complains about "lua_open".I'm using Lua 5.2.

I found alot of articles claiming that lua_open() was replaced in the fifth version but none of them mentioned with what.

Here's the code I am trying to compile

```
extern "C" {
#include "../lua/lua.h"
#include "../lua/lualib.h"
#include "../lua/lauxlib.h"
}

int main()
{
    int s=0;

    lua_State *L = lua_open();
    // load the libs
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    luaL_dofile(L,"example.lua");
    printf("\nDone!\n");
    lua_close(L);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `lua_open` was already not present in the 5.1 manual. It worked only for compatibility, which has now been removed in 5.2.

Comment: See also this very helpful stack overflow answer with an example of the lua_Alloc() function with links to the lua documentation.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880798/lua-runs-out-of-memory

Comment: Here is a second stack overflow answer giving a few more details regard lua memory allocation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324117/how-do-modern-vms-handle-memory-allocation

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Indeed, the `lua_open` function is not mentioned in the [lua 5.2 reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#4)

A `lua_State` is constructed with `lua_newstate`, and you can use `luaL_newstate` from `lauxlib.h`

A faster way to get the answers to such question is to look into the Lua 5.2 source code (which I just did).