# embed lua runtime error: Symbol not found: _luaL_newstate

Tags: c++, lua

my code

```
inline int DOFILE(string& filename) {

  printf("lua_open\n");
  /* initialize Lua */
  lua_State* L = lua_open();

  printf("lua_openlibs\n");
  /* load Lua base libraries */
  luaL_openlibs(L);

  printf("lua_dofile\n");
  /* run the script */
  int ret = luaL_dofile(L, filename.c_str());

  printf("lua_close\n");
  /* cleanup Lua */
  lua_close(L);

  return ret; 
}
```

compile options:

```
obj.cxxflags = ["-g", "-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64", "-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE", "-Wall", "-llua-5.1"]
```

also tried '-llua', '-llualib', all of them report warning

```
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2: -llua-5.1: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

When I run, it report:

```
lua_open
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _luaL_newstate
  Referenced from: /Users/gl/workspace/node-lua/build/Release/node_lua.node
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _luaL_newstate
  Referenced from: /Users/gl/workspace/node-lua/build/Release/node_lua.node
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552560/embedding-lua-in-c/8552620#8552620

Comment: Does your build system have something like a `obj.ldflags` setting? If so, put the libraries there.

Comment: @Mat I am not sure, actually I am a newb of c++, and I try to write a node-addon, using node-waf just waf. I'll google it. thanks.

Comment: @Mat you are right, I use `obj.ldflags = ['-llua']` and it works, but I still don't know what happened and why it works.

Comment: @guilin桂林: added a short explanation as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the `obj.ldflags` parameter for libraries.

The build tool you are using produces its binaries in two steps:

1. compile
2. link

The compile step uses the `obj.cxxflags` compiler flags. Libraries are not needed to compile, so passing linker flags (`-lfoo`) in there is no useful - the compiler doesn't use them at all (hence the warnings).

The link step should use both `obj.cxxflags` and `obj.ldflags`. (`ld` is the name of the linker.)

(It is not uncommon for *very simple* code to do both compiling and linking at the same time, e.g. with `g++ -o thing thing.cpp -lpthread`. But for larger builds, separating compiling and linking is usual.)