# How do modern VMs handle memory allocation?

Tags: c, memory-management, lua, vm-implementation

I'm working on a simple stack machine written in C, mostly for learning purposes. After using `malloc/free` for my memory operations, I thought it would be a good idea to read some memory allocation specific code from modern virtual machines.

I downloaded Lua source code and started reading it. After a while, I realized there are lots of macro stuff involved, and I couldn't find the code where real memory allocation is done (ie. `malloc` call).

```
find . -exec grep -i "malloc" '{}' \; -print
```

It printed only some Lua macros that have `malloc` word in their names. The Lua VM (and programming language) doesn't use `malloc` at all!

So this leads me to the question: how do modern VMs handle memory allocation? How does Lua allocate memory from the heap? Are there any ways for allocation other than `malloc`? What are the pros/cons of other methods?

I'm also wondering about best-practices, design-patterns, etc. for safely working on allocated memory. I see in Lua's source that there is lots of indirection before allocating memory. Where can I learn about this stuff?

Comment: What kind of VM's are you interested in? There are VMs that virtualize entire computers, you know. Are you asking about those too?

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze, No, I'm just interested in VMs that used for programming languages.

Comment: OK, the title looks confusing.

Comment: Is this one of those rare questions that really *should* be migrated to [programmers.se](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: @finnw Is it common for question to be incorrectly migrated to programmers.se?

Comment: @snogglethorpe, it used to be (but recently they made it more difficult)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Lua most definitely uses `malloc`, in the form of `realloc` (one can also pass a custom allocator too), however, because Lua uses a GC like 99% of VM based languages, it uses the macros to automatically add the GC header block to the allocation.

You'll find Lua's memory all handled by the `LuaM_` routines in `lmem.c` and `lmem.h`, these all use the global state of the VM to store an allocator, which is initially set to `l_alloc` (from `lauxlib.c`), but can be changed by `lua_setallocf`.

Recently, LuaJIT added allocation sinking and plans for some really cool memory features, which you can read up on this article on [LuaJIT Garbage Collection](http://wiki.luajit.org/New-Garbage-Collector). The article covers a lot of strategy and design revolving around VM/JIT memory allocation, sinking, aggregation, and garbage collecting.

As you can see, memory allocation and sinking strategies are very closely link to the GC one employs (if any).

In terms of pro's and con's of various memory *allocators*, using standard `malloc` is simple to use, but at the cost of speed and wastage to alignment and various extra blocks tagged on to each allocation.

Moving to more advanced arena, pool, slab and block allocators, we can speed things up dramatically (especially for fixed size internal VM allocations) and avoid a lot of the fragmentation and overhead that can occur with more general allocators such as `malloc`, but of course these allocators are more complex, and you have to debug them if you start from scratch (which in a bigger system like a VM is just asking for problems), as apposed to the tried-and-tested CRT `malloc` implementation.

Comment: Thanks, can you show me where is it using `malloc`, because like I've said, I can't find it. I'm planning to trace the code from malloc used to understand internals better.

Comment: @sinan: lemme dig it up quick

Comment: Thanks, but isn't a `malloc` or `calloc` call required for `realloc`? So there should be some `malloc` or `calloc` calls ..

Comment: Yes, but LUA source code does not contain the realloc source code, as realloc is a standard function, and is part of the C runtime. To see realloc source code, you would have to download the source code for glibc, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: @sinan No, you can use `realloc(3)` without ever using `malloc(3)`. From the manpage: _If ptr is NULL, realloc() is identical to a call to malloc() for size bytes._

Answer (score 5):

The Lua core does not use `malloc` and friends. It relies on a user-supplied memory allocation function that has `realloc`-like semantics (but is more precise when treating `NULL` pointers and sizes of 0). See [lua_Alloc](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_Alloc).

The auxiliary Lua library provides a convenience `luaL_newstate` function that creates a Lua state via the core `lua_newstate` function using a memory allocation function based on standard  `realloc` and `free`. Other clients can use whatever memory allocation is suitable for their app.